# jquery get css property font-weight returning number instead of 'bold' in IE

Tags: jquery, css, fonts

I'm trying to get the font-weight of a property using latest jquery, doesn't work in IE somehow... on IE dev toolbar console -

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1').css('font-weight')
```

returns

700 !

I checked in the source... can't see any problems with the style formatting. Works in FF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing out of the ordinary there, as bold is synonymous with 700.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness

> The font labeled "Bold" will often correspond to the weight value '700'.

Answer (score 0):

ye, just realised that.. think jQuery should return the same value tho across browsers... I'm using this now

```
...
fontWeight = $(this).css('font-weight');
if (fontWeight == 'bold' || fontWeight == '700') {
...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. FYI, This'd be more a comment than an answer.

Comment: ye I thought so too.. but can I put a code block in comment? If not, will seem messy.

Comment: by for now, chrome(v27) gives "bold" but FF(v21) and IE(v10) gives "700" for the getter `$(".selector").css("font-weight")` for bolded texts.so your `Or` is fine by for now.