# Javascript .css("font-weight") change of behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Javascript method to check if an element has a bold font-weight.

```
function selected(element) {
    return element.css("font-weight") === "bold";
}
```

This used to work but recently I realised that it has stopped working.

Even though in inspection, the element's CSS is identical to before:

```
<td title="Example" style="font-weight: bold; color: black;">EXAMPLE</td>
```

The above function returns false.

That is because, `element.css("font-weight")` returns a number instead (700).

I have changed my function to:

```
function selected(element) {
    return element.css("font-weight") === "bold" || element.css("font-weight") === "700";
}
```

And it works. Anyone knows why? I am using Chrome 62.0.3202.94, does that play a role?

Comment: ^ `>==` is not a thing.

Comment: When would that value be more than 700? Why are you proposing `>= 700` and not `=== 700`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan [This is NOT true](https://jsfiddle.net/rcnkrq3o/1/). It is in fact a string.

Comment: Bold is 700, normal is 400, and each font-weight value in text has a number, check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Comment: @ErikKralj It appears my testing was flawed - you're correct. I deleted my comment

Comment: @pk1914 `font-weight` goes up to `900` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Comment: so I should do something like `parseInt(countryClicked.css("font-weight")) >= 700;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the names `bolder, bold, normal` all maps up to the numerical values for the weight of the fonts. There are more possible numerical values than literal names in CSS thus jQuery returns the numerical value instead of the names of the weight.

I would suggest you remove the check for `=== "bold"` at all because it is never going to return that value.

Check this:
http://htmldog.com/references/css/properties/font-weight/

Comment: That makes sense, but why was this working 1 month ago or so?

Comment: I am not much informed about this particular method and CSS property, but updates to jQuery and / or the browsers may have affected it. They might have realized later it is better to return only one type of font weight value. We are free to check the source code of jQuery, give it a try and see what you can find!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `element.style.fontWeight` to access that property to keep using `=== "bold"`

Answer (score 1):

**This is a jQuery thing.** Apparently the `.css()` [function checks for computed `CSS` styles](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/94ddf620224d6555aaa7eaac20c583b15c6f50d8/src/css.js#L329).

```js
(function () {
  var el = document.getElementById('el');
  $('#val0').html(window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue("font-weight"));
  $('#val1').html(el.style.fontWeight);
  $('#val2').html($('#el').css("font-weight"));
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="el" style="font-weight: bold;">EXAMPLE</span>
<p>
  Value of font-weight in plain Javascript: <span id="val1"></span>
</p>
<p>
  Value of computed font-weight in plain Javascript: <span id="val0"></span>
</p>
<p>
  Value of font-weight in jQuery: <span id="val2"></span>
</p>
```

Similar question [jquery get css property font-weight returning number instead of 'bold' in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115606/jquery-get-css-property-font-weight-returning-number-instead-of-bold-in-ie)
.